# Delete all rows if duplicate in excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I need to remove all rows without leaving any unique record. If duplicate exists delete all matching rows. Criteria is column C if any duplicate record exists in column C then delete entire row (including unique).

Below given code is working but leaving the unique row Even I don't want that.

Code:

```
Sub DDup()

    Sheets("MobileRecords").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 3), Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @fbonetti Please help as this code was provided by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the code from Jeeped, but it isn't the best readable one. Therefore, here is another solution.

```
Sub remDup()
Dim rng As Range, dupRng As Range, lastrow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim col As Long, offset As Long, found As Boolean

'Disable all the stuff that is slowing down
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Define your worksheet here
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

'Define your column and row offset here
col = 3
offset = 0

'Find first empty row
Set rng = ws.Cells(offset + 1, col)
lastrow = rng.EntireColumn.Find( _
                What:="", After:=ws.Cells(offset + 1, col)).Row - 1

'Loop through list
While (rng.Row < lastrow)
    Do
        Set dupRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(rng.Row + 1, col), ws.Cells(lastrow, col)).Find( _
                What:=rng, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If (Not (dupRng Is Nothing)) Then
            dupRng.EntireRow.Delete
            lastrow = lastrow - 1
            found = True
            If (lastrow = rng.Row) Then Exit Do
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Set rng = rng.offset(1, 0)

    'Delete current row
    If (found) Then
        rng.offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        lastrow = lastrow - 1
    End If

    found = False
Wend

'Enable stuff again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

It works with more than one duplicate and you can define an row offset, which defines how much rows you ignore at the beginning of the column.

Comment: Thanks @Mr K it worked but it takes too long (around 2-3 minutes) isn't there a way to reduce that ? or it has to take the same just curious because if anything is done meanwhile it crashes worksheet .

Comment: Nice one. You forgot to declare a var and disabling screen updating would make it run a little faster but it works well. If the OP has a LOT of rows, maybe turn those integers into longs.

Comment: Wow, that is really too long. Must be a lot of data. If you don't care about the original order of your rows, I would suggest to sort first. The code would be much easier and faster.

If the original order is important, then build a userform (like a progressbar).

Comment: @Mr. K Yes it varies between 5k to 10K rows. How to build progress bar ? little new to VB hope you won't mind .

Comment: I forgot to define 'found' as boolean. In default mode, you don't have to declare any variables. But if you project becomes larger, I strongly suggest to write 'Option Explicit' at the beginning of each module/sheet/userform and declare each variable you use.

Comment: Try using the code again. I disabled the updates (thanks to Jeeped) and other stuff to make the code faster.

Comment: Just out of intereset, how long did the code to execute in the second version?

Comment: 1/4th time of first Code .

Comment: @MrK please help need your expertise again as need little tweek in your codes, please refer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454779/cross-missing-field-updation-from-different-rows-in-excel.

Comment: @SK - This is not a place to make appointments with your personal arsenal of free programmers. Show some initiative and write some code yourself. You will find that you will receive prompt, focused help with an actual coding problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like to try these without any declared variables. It is good practise for keeping your cell / worksheet / workbook hierarchy together.

```
Sub dupeNuke()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~~ you should know what worksheet you are supposed to be on
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 2)
                With .FormatConditions
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF(C:C, C2)>1"
                End With
                With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                    .Interior.Color = vbRed
                End With
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 2)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vbRed, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, Cells)) Then
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End With
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 2)
                With .FormatConditions
                    .Delete
                End With
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Obviously, this is heavily reliant on the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). An underrated / underused method in my estimation.

Comment: ... and overused in your answer ;)

Comment: Perhaps, but I still see it preferable to a dozen `Set rngX = ...` and for next loops that run the height of the used range. I'll take With ... End With over Select and Activate any day.

Comment: Hello @Jeeped it is producing Error 400 and deletes all the records. I tried to debug so found that it also not marking red to all duplicate cells and also to some which are unique . please help .

Comment: I ran that on sample data successfully but obviously my sample data is not the same as yours. I would have to see some redacted sample data in order to debug. Can you put some data on google-drive or dropbox and stick a link into your question above?

Comment: @Jeeped please help need your expertise again as need little tweek in your codes, please refer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454779/cross-missing-field-updation-from-different-rows-in-excel.