# Delete duplicate row in excel by comparing a column

Tags: vba, excel

Given below is an example of data i'm working with
As you can see it has duplicate entries.(actual database is 30000 entries)

I would like to find a method on how I can remove duplicate rows base on the corresponding column where percentage is listed.

The method should compare duplicate row percentages and choose the highest one and discard the other

This the question(initial):
[image]

**I hope its clear with this output.
This is the result, I want**
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It will (should) sort the data by the email and percentage column, then remove duplicates leaving the highest percentage intact.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Sort _
        Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, KEY2:=Range("B1"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    .Range("A1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: +1 for very short answer. But add "Order2:=xlDescending" to your sort command. Otherwise it uses your default value, which can be different from others.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this method once you can do it manually.

**Step 1:** Sort by percentage descending.

**Step 2:** Use the 'Remove Duplicates' function on the data ribbon. Use it on the 'Email' column only.

Answer (score 1):

### 1- clic DATA tab

[image]

### 2-select your data and clic **Remove Duplicates**

[image]

3-Select corresponding columns and clic OK.

Comment: I am sorry, but it's not something I am asking for, how will it be succeeding in keeping the highest percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an altered version of the following post:
[Delete all rows if duplicate in excel - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403207/delete-all-rows-if-duplicate-in-excel-vba/35405143#35405143)

```
Sub remDup2()
    Dim rng As Range, dupRng As Range, lastrow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long, col2 As Long, offset As Long, deletecurrent As Boolean

    'Disable all the stuff that is slowing down
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Define your worksheet here
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    'Define your column and row offset here
    col = 1    'Column with E-Mail
    col2 = 2   'Column with percentage
    offset = 1 'Startrow with entries

    'Find first empty row
    Set rng = ws.Cells(offset + 1, col)
    lastrow = rng.EntireColumn.Find( _
                What:="", After:=ws.Cells(offset + 1, col)).Row - 1

    'Loop through list
    While (rng.Row < lastrow)
        Do
            Set dupRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(rng.Row + 1, col), ws.Cells(lastrow, col)).Find( _
                    What:=rng, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If (Not (dupRng Is Nothing)) Then
                If (ws.Cells(rng.Row, col2) > ws.Cells(dupRng.Row, col2)) Then
                    dupRng.EntireRow.Delete
                    lastrow = lastrow - 1
                Else
                    deletecurrent = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                If (lastrow = rng.Row) Then Exit Do
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        Set rng = rng.offset(1, 0)

        'Delete current row
        If (deletecurrent) Then
            rng.offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            lastrow = lastrow - 1
        End If

        deletecurrent = False
    Wend

    'Enable stuff again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```